# Why does my MS Word Table of Contents change page number formatting randomly?

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-office, microsoft-word-2007

Okay.  I have a Microsoft word document that I've cleaned up to illustrate my issue.  The document was created in Word 2007.  You can find it here: https://www.dropbox.com/s/7gr69bqa1t1izr2/Sample.docx

My issue is the TOC formatting.  I am using an automatically generated TOC, but my issue is that elements of my paper using identical styles are showing up in my TOC formatted differently.  I've put a lot of work into customizing styles, and I use this document as a template for lots of different papers.

Here is a screenshot: [image: Messed up TOC]

It seems that, at random, certain sections of my TOC (like "Team", "Vision", "Values", "Steps", etc.) decide to do without the ellipses and right justification of page numbers.  Does anyone have any idea what is going on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I worked on your sample you provided through the DropBox.  I have it completed and figured out.

Basically the issue that you are facing is that the indentations (within the actual table of contents), you can modify the indentations if you double click on the body of the table of contents.  If you look at your ruler you can see that the indentations are off a little bit on those items that are not formatted correctly.

Here is the link that helped me out: [Table of Contents Formatting](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/office/forum/office_2003-word/in-the-table-of-contents-some-page-numbers-are-not/cc3d5a1e-22b5-4e5c-8065-05d038a2f99b)

Here is the link to the OneDrive file: [OneDrive File](https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=7E8578264BAF5B25!256&authkey=!AOIRK2Pf9raA388&ithint=file,.doc)

I would have a DropBox link, but I haven't received their validation email to get my account registered.

Hope this all helps.

Comment: Okay, I didn't totally understand your post, but the TOC Formatting link you posted was helpful.  I think I can get all of my TOC's fixed now, by just getting rid of the hanging indent.  Thanks!